# WiFi to Ethernet adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, wireless-adapter

I've a WiFi router which doesn't have an Ethernet port. Is there a way I could connect my DVR to it via a device which receives the internet wirelessly from the WiFi router and sends it to DVR through LAN port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, and it is easy: Most (al cheapo) Wireless Access Points know a so called "client mode", where they reverse their activity: Instead of creating a WLAN from a wired LAN, the create a LAN port that is connected to the WLAN.

**EDIT**

This is especially usefull to create a house-to house WLAN bridge.

Comment: I was doubtful if there's such a device. Could you name a few? Or at least tell how they're called in the market? Bit confused with the type of devices like range extender, WiFi adapter, etc..

Comment: The TP-Link 7210 is cheap and works well, same with the WR702N

Comment: I bought this one: TP-Link TL-WA850RE 300Mbps Universal WiFi Range Extender. And it's exactly what I was looking for!